# Richtext custom buttons do not load initially when using content control

Tags: dojo, ckeditor, xpages, rich-text-editor, xpages-extlib

I have a rich text field inside a dynamic content control from exension library. In the rich text field I have set a few attributes to show specific buttons.

My problem is that the initial load of the rich text field does not display the custom buttons, I need to click the link to load the buttons. It does not seem to matter if the key is in the url or not, same results.

How can I make sure the attributes buttons are loaded initially?

Here is the code for you to try for your self, paste it in to a new xpage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<div style="width:300px;padding:20px">

    <xp:link escape="true" text="Load Content"
        id="link2">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.showContent("#{id:dynC}","key1")]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:link>
    <br /><br />
    <xe:dynamicContent id="dynC" useHash="true">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:panel xp:key="key1">
                <xp:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoDocument var="d" formName="Doc"></xp:dominoDocument>
                </xp:this.data>

                <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"
                    value="#{d.Body}">
                    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                        <xp:dojoAttribute name="toolbar">
                            <xp:this.value>
                                <![CDATA[#{javascript:"[['FontSize'],['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'],['TextColor','BGColor']," +
     "['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','NumberedList','BulletedList']," +
"['Outdent','Indent']," +
"['RemoveFormat','-','MenuPaste','-','Undo','Redo','-', 'Image','Table','Link'],['Source']]"}]]>
                            </xp:this.value>
                        </xp:dojoAttribute>
                    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>

                </xp:inputRichText>
            </xp:panel>
                </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:dynamicContent>
    </div>
</xp:view>
```

This is what it looks like after initial load

[image]

This is what it looks like after clicking the link

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm getting something wrong here, but the toolbar that you define via the attribute of your inputRichText seems to be exactly the one that is shown in the first screenshot (for the initial load). So this is not unexpected, or is it?

Comment: If you have manually modified the CKEditor config such that the default toolbar should look like in the second screenshot, then you just have to remove the toolbar-dojo-attribute from the markup of your inputRichText and your custom toolbar should already be shown on initial load.

Comment: you are absolutely right, my bad,